# How can I extract the value of html TH tags that occur multiple times in a text file using a bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a text file that contains html markup. I would like to extract the values in this section:

```html
<th scope="col" class="text-center">158</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">139 (87.97%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">18 (11.39%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">1 (0.63%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
```

The values change from time to time but there will always be only 6 of thesr tags. I've tried doing something like this:

```
text="$(cat email_resp.txt | grep -n '<th scope="col" class="text-center">' | sort)"
```

I also tried this as well:

```
text2="$(sed -n '/<th scope="col" class="text-center">/,/<\/th>/p' email_resp.txt)"
```

But what I get is like a "blob" of text and I'm not able to iterate over it.

```
689:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">158</th>
690:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">139 (87.97%)</th>
691:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">18 (11.39%)</th>
692:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
693:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">1 (0.63%)</th>
694:                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
```

This is the output when I use the sed command:

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center">158</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">139 (87.97%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">18 (11.39%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">1 (0.63%)</th>
<th scope="col" class="text-center">0 (0.00%)</th>
```

Ideally what I would like to do is extract those values between the `<th>` tags into an array or variables so that I can use them elsewhere.

Comment: I would certainly recommend an array. For a text file of the form you specified, it would be sufficient to extract everything between `>` and `<`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash


source <(
        awk -F'<th scope="col" class="text-center">|</th>' '
                BEGIN{print "declare -a myArr1=(" }
                NF==3{print "\047"$2"\047"}
                END{print ")"}
        ' file
)

declare -a myArr2="(
        $(
                awk -F'<th scope="col" class="text-center">|</th>' '
                     NF==3{print "\047"$2"\047"}
                ' file
        )
)"

declare -p myArr1
declare -p myArr2
```

---

```
declare -a myArr1=([0]="158" [1]="139 (87.97%)" [2]="18 (11.39%)" [3]="0 (0.00%)" [4]="1 (0.63%)" [5]="0 (0.00%)")
declare -a myArr2=([0]="158" [1]="139 (87.97%)" [2]="18 (11.39%)" [3]="0 (0.00%)" [4]="1 (0.63%)" [5]="0 (0.00%)")
```

Comment: Tx ufopilot, the `source..` snippet does what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk and split the line into tokens using either `<` or `>` as delimiters.

```
cat email_resp.txt | grep -P "<th scope=\"col\" class=\"text-center\">" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "<|>"; } { print $3; }'
```

Comment: is grep -P a valid option, when I try it I get this grep: invalid option -- P

Comment: Tried it as grep -p and it works

Comment: On my Debian, -P is for Perl regular expression.

Comment: `-P` is for PCREs and only available in GNU grep. There's nothing PCRE-specific about the regexp being used, it's just a plain old BRE as grep uses by default, so you can just remove the `-P` for improved performance and portability. The rule for quoting in shell is to use single quotes until if/when you **need** double quotes - if you follow that rule you don't need to escape the double quotes inside the regexp - `grep '<th scope="col" class="text-center">'` but you also don't need `grep` at all when you're using `awk` and you don't need `cat` when you're using either one.

Comment: To demonstrate that last point - the pipeline of multiple commands `cat email_resp.txt | grep -P "<th scope=\"col\" class=\"text-center\">" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "<|>"; } { print $3; }'` could be written as the single command `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "<|>"; } /<th scope="col" class="text-center">/{ print $3; }' email_resp.txt`

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Awk 4 and above, you can do this:

```
$ sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/' markup.txt | 
    awk '
         BEGIN{
             PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
         }
         { arr[NR]=$0 }
         END{
             for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]
         }
    '
```

Comment: You don't need sed when you're using awk. `sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/' file | awk '{arr[NR]=$0}'` = `awk '{arr[NR]=gensub(/.*>(.*)<.*/,"\\1",1)}' file` using GNU awk. It's not obvious what your intent with the awk script is at all though - it'll print the input it's getting from `sed` with line-numbers in front but `cat -n` or similar could do that and even in awk it'd just be `awk '{print NR, $0}'`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Ideally what I would like to do is extract those values between the th tags into an array or variables so that I can use them elsewhere. ..."*

You can use the *"--perl-regexp"* and *"--only-matching"* switches, with *[grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)*.

```
grep -Po '(?<=<th scope="col" class="text-center">).+(?=</th>)' data.txt
```

```
158
139 (87.97%)
18 (11.39%)
0 (0.00%)
1 (0.63%)
0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `GNU sed`:

you can capture the output in a variable as below:

```
var=$(sed -rn 's#.*class="text-center">(.*)</th>#\1#p' file_name)
```

Explanation:

```
-r        use extended regular expressions in the script.
-n        suppress automatic printing of pattern space
using '#' as separator and trying to capture only the required field inside '()' and printing the first captured group using \1
```

output:

```
echo "$var"
158
139 (87.97%)
18 (11.39%)
0 (0.00%)
1 (0.63%)
0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t arr < <(
    sed -n 's/.*<th scope="col" class="text-center">\(.*\)<\/th>.*/\1/p' "${@:--}"
)

declare -p arr
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
declare -a arr=([0]="158" [1]="139 (87.97%)" [2]="18 (11.39%)" [3]="0 (0.00%)" [4]="1 (0.63%)" [5]="0 (0.00%)")
```

or using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t arr < <(
    awk '
        match($0,/<th scope="col" class="text-center">(.*)<\/th>/,a) {
            print a[1]
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
)

declare -p arr
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
declare -a arr=([0]="158" [1]="139 (87.97%)" [2]="18 (11.39%)" [3]="0 (0.00%)" [4]="1 (0.63%)" [5]="0 (0.00%)")
```

or there's various options using any awk, including:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t arr < <(
    awk '
        match($0,/<th scope="col" class="text-center">.*<\/th>/) {
            print substr($0,RSTART+36,RSTART-36+RLENGTH-6)
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
)

declare -p arr
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
declare -a arr=([0]="158" [1]="139 (87.97%)" [2]="18 (11.39%)" [3]="0 (0.00%)" [4]="1 (0.63%)" [5]="0 (0.00%)")
```